# Linkedin support contact

Tags: linkedin-api

I am looking for LinkedIn support because when we implemented the web everything was working perfectly but now I am getting a Request token retrieval failed.

```
        [oauth_problem] => Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : rw_groups, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : rw_nus, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_network, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_contactinfo, Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_fullprofile
```

[error] => OAuth callback URL was not confirmed by the LinkedIn end-point

and it is showing my private keys after this error. I need help.

Answer (score 1):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs to only support the following uses:**

- Allowing members to represent their professional identity via their LinkedIn profile using their Profile API.
- Enabling members to post certifications directly to their LinkedIn profile with their Add to Profile tools.
- Enabling members to share professional content to their LinkedIn network from across the Web leveraging their Share API.
- Enabling companies to share professional content to LinkedIn with their Company API.

**Access to the above mentioned scopes requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

**SOLUTION:**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of "we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn," then some or all of the restricted endpoints will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

**Member profile fields**

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:

1. Basic Profile Fields
2. Location Fields
3. Position Fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers:**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the [Apply with LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) use case:

1. Full Profile Fields
2. Contact Info Fields
3. Company Fields
4. Publication Fields
5. Patent Fields
6. Language Fields
7. Skill Fields
8. Certification Fields
9. Course Fields
10. Education Fields
11. Volunteer Fields

**Check out this [linkedin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) for more details on which fields are available to all the developers and which are not.**